# Употребление буквы "ять"

Tags: старая-грамматика

Читала, что буква "ять" писалась в тех словах, у которых в украинском Е изменяется на И. Например: "лес - лiс, резать - рiзати" и т.д. Так ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, рефлекс ятя в русском - Е, в украинском - И, в польском - Я. 
Правда закономерность эта не абсолютная, в отдельных русских словах ять перешёл в Ё (звёзды), аналогичные редкие нарушения правила есть и в украинском.